# How to make raster from points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, point

[image: Points]

I have these points and I want to make raster from this layer based on Dist2River attribute.

I used Rasterize

[image: Rsterize]

What should put for these to create a normal raster?

Comment: Look for the tool *Rasterize (vector to raster)*

Comment: [here is a tutorial on the rasterizing points](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-create-raster-from-points-in-qgis/), Then you just have to try different options until you get an idea of how the tool works and the result you want. BTW the linked tutorial is the second google answer for "point to raster qgis tutorial", Please do some research and show what you tried before asking for help here, this is a problem-solving site.